# Joomla 3.x jQuery conflict butween library's jQuery mootools but noConflict seems not to work

Tags: jquery, conflict

I have a joomla site and in a article  I call a HTML page.

In this html page I have created something with the [bx-slider](http://bxslider.com/) in combination with vertical scroller, so that anchor links that scrolls smoothly to the anchor on the page (see tutorial of adriantomic.se jquery localscroll tutorial

This is working fine! No problem.

But now I call this page in a joomla article by php: 
    . 
This is also not a problem. But this template is from joomlart (puresite) and I get  a conflict error which I don't understand:

```
TypeError: jmega.getElement is not a function
http://reset.nl/templates/puresite/js/mega.rjd.js
Line 25

TypeError: $(...).ready is not a function
http://reset.nl/media/system/js/mootools-core.js
Line 28
```

I have tried different variants by noConflict but it doesn't help. If I change jQuery(document.function($), then it seems that the some function is running into a endless loop.

Does anybody have a idea how to solve this?

Nico.
Here is my code of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
        <link href="/components/com_scroll_content/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!-- Some CSS -->
       <style type="text/css">
       /* CSS for the big boxes */
           .box {
              width: 300px;
              height: 300px;

              color: #fff;
              padding: 10px;

              margin: 100px 0 0 0;
           }

           #box1 {
              margin: 300px 0 0 0;
              background: blue;
           }

           #box2 {
              background: red;
           }

           #box3 {
              background: green;
           }

           #box4 {
              background: gray;
           }

           /* CSS for the small boxes that will scroll inside a div */

           #small-box-container {
              border: 1px solid black;
              padding: 20px;
              width: 300px;
              height: 200px;

              overflow: scroll;
           }

           .small-box {

              color: #fff;
              padding: 10px;

              width: 200px;
              height: 200px;
              margin: 0 0 50px 0;
           }

           #small-box1 {
              background: blue;
           }

           #small-box2 {
              background: red;
           }

           #small-box3 {
              background: green;
           }
       </style>

        <!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Load jQuery This is from the joomlaart template-->
        <!--<script src="/templates/ResetFashion/js/jquery/jquery.noconflict.js"></script>-->
        <!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
        <script src="/components/com_scroll_content/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Load ScrollTo -->
        <script src="http://flesler-plugins.googlecode.com/files/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js"></script>

        <!-- Load LocalScroll -->
        <script src="http://flesler-plugins.googlecode.com/files/jquery.localscroll-1.2.7-min.js"></script>

        <script>

            //var $jQ = jQuery.noConflict();
            $(document).ready(function(){
            //(function(jQ){
            //  jQ(window).load(function(){

                $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                    minSlides: 1,
                    maxSlides: 2,
                    slideWidth: 170,
                    slideMargin: 10,
                    responsive: true
                });

                // Scroll the whole document
              $('#box-links').localScroll({
                 target:'body'
              });

              // Scroll the content inside the #scroll-container div
              $('#small-box-links').localScroll({
                 target:'#small-box-container'
              });
            });

        //})(jQuery);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="small-box-links">      
            <ul class="bxslider">
              <li><a href="#small-box1"><img src="/components/com_scroll_content/images/trees.jpg" /></a></li>
              <li><a href="#small-box2"><img src="/components/com_scroll_content/images/tree_root.jpg" /></a></li>
              <li><a href="#small-box3"><img src="/components/com_scroll_content/images/houses.jpg" /></a></li>
              <li><img src="/components/com_scroll_content/images/hill_road.jpg" /></li>
              <li><img src="/components/com_scroll_content/images/me_trees.jpg" /></li>
              <li><img src="/components/com_scroll_content/images/hill_trees.jpg" /></li>
              <li><img src="/components/com_scroll_content/images/mountain.jpg" /></li>
              <li><img src="/components/com_scroll_content/images/houses.jpg" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="small-box-container">
            <div id="small-box1" class="small-box">Small-Box #1</div>
            <div id="small-box2" class="small-box">Small-Box #2</div>
            <div id="small-box3" class="small-box">Small-Box #3</div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I rewritten your jquery code:

```
<script>
        $.noConflict();
        $(document).ready(function($){
        //(function(jQ){
        //  jQ(window).load(function(){

            $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                minSlides: 1,
                maxSlides: 2,
                slideWidth: 170,
                slideMargin: 10,
                responsive: true
            });

            // Scroll the whole document
          $('#box-links').localScroll({
             target:'body'
          });

          // Scroll the content inside the #scroll-container div
          $('#small-box-links').localScroll({
             target:'#small-box-container'
          });
        });

    //})(jQuery);
    </script>
```

Hpoe this work for you.